# Integrating two sites payment to single payment gateway in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am having two sites, say abc.com and def.com. Now abc.com is developed with nopcommerce and have a payment gateway integrated to it by nopcommerce. Now in def.com there is a payment process. Now I should be able to do payment from def.com through abc.com(payment gateway) only which is build using nopcommerce. def.com is developed in MVC with EF.
Is this possible, If possible can some one give me some inputs on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

In short, i dont think you can call nop commerce payment gateway from another application.

But there are few options to consider,

1. NopCommerce payment plug-in itself designed to be plug-able. So you can copy the payment plugin design of nopcommerce to your website and use nopcommerce plugin.
2. NopCommerce payment plug-in is also a mvc based solution. So you can add that plugin code into your application as a part of your website.